# How to use Multiprocessing in python with Function which usess SQL insert statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I have a Function d and i want to use this function with multiprocessing**

````
``` 
    def function(df):
           cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO [table]('a','b','c') VALUE(?,?,?)''',df['a'],df[b],df[c])
           cursor.commit()
        return

    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=Someserver;'
                          'Database=somedbs'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    import multiprocessing as mp
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    df = somedata

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        pool.apply_async(function, args=(index,row))
    pool.close()
```
````

this is not working

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the expected behavior? Otherwise it is difficult to understand what _"not working"_ means. Also a mention about what the axtual behavior might help.

Comment: I have a Huge data computations involved in function( df) and the size of the df is 15 billion rows  so i wanted to use parallel processing to insert computed values into sql table

Comment: Why not to cursor through the whole dataset and commit at the end? Overhead probably is creating connections, not inserts themselves.

Comment: I have to compute large daraframe having more than 20 trillions of rows so my ram doesn't have capacity to hold that much data